# Capture initial curve control points before subdivision

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to capture initial curve control points before subdividing it and distorting them points. So then I just want to instanciate on the initial points and not all the subdivided points.

Capture Attribute before subdivision doesn't seem to work. As you can see in the image it's instancing on all points and I want just to do it on the 4 control points of a basic circle curve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand well, you want to resample, modify the resampled point position, but keep the initial vertices in the curve (so that you can instantiate on them)? Is that it?

Comment: yes I want to instanciate only on the 4 initial control points on that deformed curve.

Comment: but these points are lost when resampled

Comment: mmm yeah you are right.... I should find other solution for doing that

Comment: maybe subdivide it in some way?

Comment: Yes, I can subdivide instead of resampling it. But capturing the points before the subdivision doesn't seem to work. I attach an image at the end of the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to choose some attribute of your curve which is invariant under subdivision and deformation. An obvious option is the 0-1 *Factor*.

In the group below, the example input curve is a 4-point Bezier Circle.

[image]

(For demonstration purposes, the *Mess With Curve* group resamples the curve, and randomly offsets its points.)

The original factor on the curve has been stored on the instances, which look up, and are set to,  the *Position* corresponding to their *Factor* on the deformed version of the curve. (You could sample the rotation as well, if wanted)

[image]

This method seems only to work in Blender 3.5 at the moment, since, on cyclic curves, there appears to be an off-by-one error in *Sample Curve* in (at least, my version of) Blender 3.41. If anybody can contradict this, I'd be grateful.

[image] (Blender 3.5 beta)

Comment: Hi @Miguel !, will look when I can. As you say, it probably depends on the order of events.. which attributes are stored where (maybe name them?) , and whether they can be picked up further down the pipeline. I Probably won't see this until tomorrow am.